# Image operations not working for multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-imaging-library

I posted a question earlier whose code didn't work for similar reasons. It didn't get much attention, so I deleted it, and found a minimal subset of the problem.

Consider the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from PIL import Image 
import PIL.TiffImagePlugin as tiff 
def f(im,i):
    im.seek(i)
    print(i) 
manual = False  
if (__name__=='__main__' and not manual):
    p = Pool()
    im = Image.open('page.tiff') 
    im.load()
    print(p.starmap(f,[(im,0),(im,1),(im,2),(im,3)]))
if(manual): 
    im = Image.open('page.tiff') 
    f(im,0) 
    f(im,1)
    f(im,2)
    f(im,3)
```

If `manual = True` (that is, without using any `multiprocessing`) then the output is :

```
C:\Users\H.P\Downloads\states\General>python mptTest.py
0
1
2
3
```

Whereas, if `manual = False` then I get an error:

```
C:\Users\H.P\Downloads\states\General>python mptTest.py
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\H.P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\H.P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 47, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "C:\Users\H.P\Downloads\states\General\mptTest.py", line 5, in f
    im.seek(i)
  File "C:\Users\H.P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 998, in seek
    if not self._seek_check(frame):
  File "C:\Users\H.P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 276, in _seek_check
    if (frame < self._min_frame or
AttributeError: 'TiffImageFile' object has no attribute '_min_frame'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mptTest.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(p.starmap(f,[(im,0),(im,1),(im,2),(im,3)]))
  File "C:\Users\H.P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 274, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\H.P\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
AttributeError: 'TiffImageFile' object has no attribute '_min_frame'
```

This `_min_frame` originates from the `__init__` of the `ImageFile.py` file. So, when it's called, it must've called the `__init__()` method.

Why does this happen? Is this a bug in `PIL`?

Comment: Are you getting this `singlethreaded` as well?

Comment: Do you mean without using `multiprocessing`? That's already shown in the question. I don't understand if you're stating something else.